# DNX SDK version 'dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-preview1-002702' failed to install

Tags: asp.net-core

When I tried to open a .Net core RC2 migrated project in my local, i get the following error message

```
---------------------------
Microsoft Visual Studio
---------------------------
DNX SDK version 'dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-preview1-002702' failed to install. The solution will use DNX SDK version ‘dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-rc1-update1’ for this session.
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

any ideas why the latest specified version of .Net core couldn't be installed in my local? What is it I am missing here?

How do I install the latest specified version?

Please share some light on this?

Comment: probably sdk in your global json is still RC1

Comment: {
  "projects": [ "src", "test" ],
  "sdk": {
    "version": "1.0.0-preview1-002702"
  }
}
This is what I am having in the global.json file, let me know what could be other reasons for this issue ?

Comment: Have you updated the tooling to Preview1?

Comment: Sounds like you didn't uninstall previous version of .NET Core rc1 or pre-rc2-final. Check Control Panel > Programs for early RC1 or RC2 Beta setups and uninstall them, then install the preview1 tooling and rc2-final runtime

Comment: @Tseng, I followed the same approach suggested by you uninstalling RC1 and then installed RC2. It works fine now. Please post it as answer and I can accept it. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error is message usually an indicator that a previous installation (.NET Core rc1 or some of the rc2 nightlies) of .NET Core Tooling/Framework wasn't uninstalled.

To validate it, go to the "Control Panel" > "Programs and features" and search for ".NET Core" or "Microsoft .NET Core" and uninstall any previous version. Then install the correct .NET Core runtime and tooling version for RC2 and it should work.

Comment: I'm getting this error when I create a new project in VS2015 on a machine that has never had any of the release candidates installed, and only the latest 'tooling' installed. I get it randomly when I try to add Entity Framework to a number of .net core mvc projects. After I get this error (which I'm still not sure why I need DNX??) my projects all start using up memory after I start debugging and then fail with a (highly appropriate for this site!) 'stackoverflow' error. Don't suppose you know what's going on there by any chance?

Comment: I am getting this error, when adding new console application to my vs2015 project. How on earth it could be?